# how to get number of posts in a category on a specific date

Tags: categories, loop

I want to get the number of posts for each category on a specific date.  I think I can do the following:
- get a list of categories
- start loop
---create a query for each category and specific date
   loop and count posts
- end first loop

Is there any easier way to do this?

I plan to put this in the php code widget.  Note I have quite a few categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use something like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=2013&monthnum=12&day=20&cat=5' ); 
// change cat=5 to the ID of the category you want to query from.
// change year to the year you want
// change monthnum to the month you want
// change day to the day you want

// start the loop
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
     // do loop stuff
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Above says get all posts that has ID of 5 for category and the year of 2013 and month is 12 (December) and day is 20.

Comment: I was actually wondering if there is an easier way.  Is there any performance cost to this?

Comment: It is no different in performance than the regular loop.